# How do I convert a QGIS 1.8 plugin to QGIS2.0?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have developed a plugin under QGIS1.8
and now I want to make it work on QGIS2.0

I have chage qgisMinimumVersion into 2.0(originally 1.8)

but QGIS2.0 still give me the error say

```
This plugin is incompatible with this version of QGIS
Plugin designed for QGIS 1.x
```

how to fix it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First:** 
Change the `qgisMinimumVersion` in your metadata.txt and `__init__.py` file (the latter one is deprecated).

For instance like this:

```
[general]
name=your plugins name
qgisMinimumVersion=2.0
```

**Second:**
From QGIS 1.8 to QGIS 2.0 many changes in the python plugin api have been made. Your plugin might not work anymore and you might have to edit some lines of code. This site in the wiki shows you how:
http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20

Comment: Make sure you read the API docs.  Things have changed and I can almost say 100% that it will need to be updated.

Comment: @NathanW thank you for your advise! what I need is fully update my code now, it's a big deal! Is there any tool to help me to do it??